# How to find out the maximum Ampere that an IGBT can withstand

Tags: igbt

I want to replace an IGBT on my board with a new one. But when I Googled the old one (G40N60 UFD C13AK), I couldn't find its Datasheet to find out its maximum Ampere. Is there another way to find its Ampere?

> Thanks for all who answered my question. As for the -1 votes, the
>   main question I asked is for an alternative way to find the maximum
>   Ampere an IGBT can withstand in case I couldn't find the datasheet.
>   Which was answered by JonRB.

Comment: How long you googled? I tried and the datasheet pdf was the second link.

Comment: The other way is via its part number. IGBT's are (almost) always consistent in having two groups of number in their name, these represent the current and the voltage. Also considering IGBT are typically only available in 600V, 1200V, 1500V, 1700V ... you can deduce which number is voltage and which is current. NOTE: this isn't to be relied upon as every now and again someone comes along and does their own scheme but Infineon, Semikron etc are extremely consistent in this

Comment: @JonRB Thank you so much for such an explanation, really appreciated. So in case of G40N60, the 40 is the Ampere & the 60 is 600V.

Comment: exactly. you shouldn't rely on it, but 99 times out of 100 it is a good indication

Comment: @JonRB Please add your comment as an answer to accept it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a 600V 40A IGBT from Fairchild. FGH40N60UFD.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I just Googled again for G40N60 and I found its datasheet http://www.datasheetgo.com/g40n60-pdf/ When I Googled it a few days ago, I'm certain this link wasn't there nor any datasheet about it, it took me hours back then. Is it safe to assume that G40N60UFD is FGH40N60UFD?

Comment: @AshrafAlshahawy The G40N60UFD is synonymous to the FGH40N60UFD, but obviously have a different SKU number